Can a "granted" patent still be revoked for new prior art discovery by USPTO?
Once the USPTO has published an invention, waited for the priority time (i.e., 18 months), completed a prior art search, and granted a patent, can it still be revoked by the USPTO if new prior art is discovered in a scientific journal published five years back from the patent's granting date?

There are processes for challenging a patent grant. Is this what you mean or are you talking about something solely within the USPTO?

@EricS Primarily, within USPTO. However, you can answer addressing both cases.

To my knowledge the USPTO won’t do anything on their own. This article summarizes the other options. https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/how-to-challenge-a-patent-in-the-pto-4643150/

The USPTO will not do anything unless a third party initiates a process.
From the article linked to in a comment

The PTO provides three procedures by which a patent can be challenged: inter partes review (IPR), post grant review (PGR), and ex parte reexamination.

They have different rules, side effects, costs and likelihood of success.
